# What types of information should go in the body of a FogBugz case?

Tags: fogbugz

We've been having a discussion, where I work, about what type of information should go in the body of a FogBugz case.  I'm talking about the large free-text field just under the "Opened by" text when you create a new bug, or when you push Edit on an existing case.

For instance, we all agree that a detailed description of the bug belongs there, and we usually put that description in, when we first create a bug.  But in later edits, what types of information can/should be placed in there?

The biggest issue that we don't all agree on is whether design discussion belongs in there.  Something like this:

```
    FEATURE 714
    Opened by 'Person A'
    We need to provide a user with the ability to quiggle-fy the doodad.

    Edited by 'Person B'
    Do you think this will involve changing the crabbadonk interface as well?

    Edited by 'Person C'
    No, the crabbadonk is already quiggle-fied.
```

We all agree that what Person A said belongs there, but we're unsure of whether it makes sense for the conversation between Person B and Person C to be in there as well.

What do other companies do?  Is there any generally accepted principles for what kind of information belongs in there?  Is there a better place in FogBugz for that?  Or is there a separate tool that should be used for it?

Comment: It would be _great_ if you could re-word this question to be more generally applicable to bug tracking software in general, since many people use tools _other_ than FogBugz.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not convinced that this necessarily applies to other bug tracking software.  For instance, in my previous job, we used Mantis.  Mantis has a description field, and then notes, where I think it is more obvious that this kind of stuff would belong.  Mantis draws more of a distinction between the feature/bug description and discussion about it.  But you might be right; there's a more generalized question of "does feature design discussion belong in the bug tracking software?"

Comment: I was more thinking of Jira, Trac, and Bugzilla which all have the same big text area for an initial description or comment.

Comment: Yeah, I was just looking at Trac and Bugzilla.  They both seem to have separate areas for a description and notes/comments.  And I think that's kind of what I'm getting at.  FogBugz doesn't seem to separate the two from each other.  So where would this kind of design discussion go in FogBugz?  Or should it just not go in the bug tracking software alltogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FogBugz, here is what I like to do with my projects:

1. Discussion should go on a discussion board
2. The end design should go in a Wiki
3. The tasks to implement the design should be made cases

This has the advantage of using the various "formats" in the way they work best, and also provides a *lot* of flexibility. If you need to be able to link back and forth between things, there are plugins already that make this easy, and writing your own isn't too tough (either as a bugmonkey script or a full plugin.)

Comment: I like that organization in theory, but we don't have a discussion board or a wiki (yes, even though FogBugz provides a wiki, it is completely unused).  Nor do I have the clout to make it happen.  But, so then, do you have/follow the general rule "no design discussion goes into the bug/feature tracking software"?

Comment: Sort of. It depends on the scope and scale of the issue at hand. If it's a small little things, especially one being worked out between a single designer and a single developer, then we might iterate a bit in the case itself, but once it gets to more than just a couple people or is more than a specific detail (eg. if it might affect more than one specific case), then it gets handled other places.